# AWS API Gateway: Can't map thrown error from Lambda to Method Response using Integration Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

### The issue

Using the Integration Response feature of AWS API Gateway, I can successfully handle errors thrown by Lambda. However, I'm having trouble mapping the Javascript error object to the mapping template. The error object looks like this.

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Error: ABC123",
    "errorType": "Error",
    "stackTrace": [
        "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:9:11)"
    ]
}
```

Here's my Integration Response mapping for `application/json`

```
#set($errorMessage = $input.path('$.errorMessage'))
{
    "message" : $errorMessage
}
```

### What I've tried

Using this configuration, this is the entire response returned to the client: `Unexpected 'E'`. This is one string and is not contained in a JSON object.

This `E` that's referenced in the error is the first character from my thrown error message, which is used to match the Lambda Error Regex. I know this as I briefly changed the first letter to `X` and I got `Unexpected 'X'` as the response.

When I change the first line of my mapping template to this (mapping the entire object rather than attempting to just map the `errorMessage` property)

```
#set($errorMessage = $input.path('$'))
```

I get only the stack trace from the Javascript error object.

```
{
    "message" : [
        "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:9:11)"
    ]
}
```

This would suggest that either the *entire* response object being returned to API Gateway is just the `stackTrace` property from the Javascript error. But to me, this doesn't make sense as something is picking up the `errorMessage` as thats where the `Unexpected 'E'` message is coming from.

Similarly, when I try and map the `errorType` property, I get the same error as it also starts with `E`. I can only successfully map the `message` property when I use the entire `$` input object, or just the `stackTrace` property.

What am I doing wrong here?

### Other relevant code

Here's the API Gateway Error Model. The `message` property is clearly marked as a `string` type yet it only works when I return an array. *Note: this is the default code*

```
{
    "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title" : "Error Schema",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "message" : { "type" : "string" }
    }
}
```

Here's the Lambda function code

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    throw new Error(Error: ABC123);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. The solution is to use `$input.json()` rather than `$input.path()`

Here's my new mapping template

```
{
    "errorMessage" : $input.json('$.errorMessage')
}
```